# Follow up on example computation of $\mathrm{Tor}_n$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I have a follow up question on [this question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156987/example-computation-of-operatornametorim-n):

I can't reconstruct how I got $\operatorname{Im}{d_1^\ast} = 0$ from the following chain:

$$0 \to \mathbb Z \otimes_{\mathbb Z} (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z) \xrightarrow{d_1^\ast = \cdot 284 \otimes id} \mathbb Z \otimes_{\mathbb Z} (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z) \xrightarrow{d_0^\ast=0} 0$$

Now I think $\operatorname{Im}{d_1^\ast}  = 284 \mathbb Z \otimes N$ and $\operatorname{Ker}{d_0^\ast}  = \mathbb Z \otimes (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)$.

And then $Tor^1 (\mathbb Z / 284 \mathbb Z, \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z) = (\mathbb Z \otimes \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z) / (284 \mathbb Z \otimes \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z) $.

---

Is 
$$\operatorname{Im}{d_1^\ast}  = 284 \mathbb Z \otimes (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z) $$
 and 
$$\operatorname{Ker}{d_0^\ast}  = \mathbb Z \otimes (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$$ correct ?

And what does $(A \otimes B) / (C \otimes D)$ look like? Is it isomorphic to $(A/C) \otimes (B/D)$? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your last paragraph might not be a good idea to consider. There are several problems with it. If you keep track of the maps, then things are better.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Thank you, but I do not understand your last sentence, I'm sorry. What do you mean by keeping track of the maps?

Comment: Basically, do not use $C \otimes D$ to mean a subgroup of $A \otimes B$ even if $C \leq A$ and $D \leq B$. Even if enough modules are flat that you could get a monomorphism, it can be dangerous to think like this. For instance, what is $2\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$? As a tensor product, it is an abelian group of order 2. As a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ it has order 1.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Oh, ok, right. So I guess, if I get $(A \otimes B) / (C \otimes D)$ for $Tor^n$ then I should just leave it as is and cannot simplify it any further. And what about my new results for $Im$ and $Ker$? Did I manage to get it right?

Comment: Dear Matt, The only tensor products you seem to have in sight are of the form $\mathbb Z\otimes N$.  Since I imagine that the tensor product is also taking place over $N$, these are canonically isomorphic to $N$, and so can certainly be simplified.  Regards,

Comment: Dear @MattE, I'm sorry, I forgot to replace $N$ with $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$. I have done so now.

Comment: Dear Matt, But you are still writing things like $\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z} (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$ and $(\mathbb Z/248 \mathbb Z)\otimes_{\mathbb Z} (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$, without simplifying them.  It seems that you should review how to compute tensor products before going too much further in trying to compute higher Tors.  Regards,

Comment: Dear @MattE, well I know that $(\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z) \otimes (\mathbb Z / m \mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z / \mathrm{gcd}(n,m) \mathbb Z$. Do I really have to simplify all of them, always? (using this knowledge, $\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z} (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ and $(\mathbb Z/248 \mathbb Z)\otimes_{\mathbb Z} (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$)

Comment: In any case, before I simplify I first need to know whether I got $Ker$ and $Im$ right this time.

Comment: Actually, I'm quite sure they are correct.

Comment: Dear Matt, I don't understand your remark about needing to do other things before you simplify.  When computing Tor, you take a free resolution of one of your modules, which involves terms like $\mathbb Z^n$.  You then tensor with your second module, say $N$.  The very first step is to replace all the expressions $\mathbb Z^n \otimes_{\mathbb Z} N$ by $N^n$; so in your case you certainly will want to replace all that $\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z/2$'s by $\mathbb Z/2$'s.  Once you have the terms of the complex computed, you will then want to describe the maps, and then compute ...

Comment: ... their kernels and images explicitly; not in terms of objects expressed in convoluted terms by various unsimplified tensor products.  Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description of the image is not correct.

You would do well to heed Jack Schmidt's warning in the comments: although
$248\mathbb Z$ is a submodule of $\mathbb Z$, this is no longer true once you
tensor with $\mathbb Z/2$.  So your description of the image is not only incorrect, but the candidate image you have written down is not a subobject of the target.

I think you would also do well to follow my advice in the comments above, and to simplify the various tensor products in your complex , and then describe the maps in terms of the simplified objects, *before* you try to
 compute its cohomology.

Comment: Dear MattE, thank you so much for your help and patience. I have tried again, here is what I did:

(The ring over which we tensor is $\mathbb Z$.) I start with 
$$ 0 \to \mathbb Z \otimes \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z \otimes \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z \to 0$$

Then I used $R \otimes_R M \cong M$ to get
$$ 0 \to \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z \to 0$$

Then I used the isomorphism $R \otimes_R M \cong M$, $m \mapsto 1 \otimes m$, to compute the new maps:
$$ m \in \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z \mapsto 1 \otimes z \mapsto 284 \otimes z \mapsto 284z \equiv_2 0$$

Comment: So that the new chain complex is 
$$ 0 \to \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z \to 0$$

Comment: From which I compute the homology (I thought it was homology groups, but maybe it's cohomology?) as
$$ Tor^1 (M,N) =  \mathrm{Ker}(0) / \mathrm{Im}(0)  = \mathrm{Ker}(0) = \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$$

Comment: Is this correct? Again, I apologise for the typos in my OP yesterday, it was a long day.

Comment: @MattN : Dear Matt, Your chain complex in the comments is correct, and so is your computation of $Tor_1$.  This is right way to go --- simplify everything in sight, at which point you can hope that the relevant images and kernels are easy to compute, as they were in this example.  [Sorry, I wrote cohomology rather than homology just out of habit; I'm used to thinking of things as cochain complexes.]  Best wishes,

Comment: Dear @MattE, thank you very much for checking my computation and teaching me how to compute $\mathrm{Tor}$.